# How can I call a trait's non-static method from a static method with PHP7?

Tags: php, static-methods, traits

```
trait ClearFolder
{
    public function clearFolder($dir)
    {
        //codes...
    }

    public function clearInFolder($dir)
    {
        $this->clearFolder($dir);

        mkdir($dir);
    }
}
```

```
use boot\library\traits\ClearFolder;

class FileCache
{
    //codes....

    use ClearFolder;
    public static function clearAll()
    {
        //Case1. Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object...   
        $this->clearInFolder(self::$storage . '/');

        //Case2. Non-static method boot\libr... should not be called statically 
        self::clearInFolder(self::$storage . '/');

        //Case3. Cannot instantiate trait...
        $trait = new ClearFolder;

    }
}
```

To use a non-static method of another class inside a static method, I have to create an instance with the new keyword. But I can't use 'new' with a trait.

And I use 'declare (strict_types = 1);' and ' error_reporting(E_ALL);'.

Should I change the trait's method statically and replace everything that uses the trait?

Comment: If you wanna do that, you have a problem with overall code design. Also, NO, the answer is no since you can not instantiate a trait.

Comment: Traits aren't classes. I would recommend reading through [the manual about traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php): _"It is not possible to instantiate a Trait on its own"_.

Comment: From what I can see you are trying to use a trait as a namespace for helper methods. You could consider converting a trait into a class and public methods of this trait into static methods. Although THIS code design is not flawless by any means, it's far better compared to what you have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a non static function from a trait you must create a instance:

```
trait trait1
{
    public function dummy()
    {
      var_dump("fkt dummy");
    }
}
class c1{
  use trait1;

  public static function static1(){
    (new static)->dummy();
  }
}

c1::static1();  //string(9) "fkt dummy"
```

Or you declare your function in the trait as static:

```
trait trait1
{
    public static function dummy()
    {
      var_dump("fkt dummy");
    }
}
class c1{
  use trait1;
} 

c1::dummy(); //string(9) "fkt dummy"
```

Not nice, but works. But you should not use this without thinking about your code design.